# AJAX Enabled WebApplication

Tags: ajax, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

does sy know why the Ajax Enable WebAppication in VS 2008, even if you put the target framework 3.5, target afterwards .NET 2.0 framework?

(so I create the Web application with ASP.NET 2.0 Ajax Extensions 1.0 features enable (.NET framework 3.5) , then I check the Target Framework in the Application Tab of the project properties and it's written 2.0)

do I need to install sg more on my machine ?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET 3.5 is basically ASP.NET 2.0 + System.Web.Extensions - The same model as AJAX extensions but with different version numbers and extensions is included in a web application project by default.

Comment: The thing is that I tried to do the same than in there : http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/071107-1.aspx

but I could not generate in the codebehind the method call to get the content ("
the Add Dynamic Populate ..."part)

but finally I made it manually and all works fine

thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try just create ASP.NET Web Application.  Select .NET Framework 3.5 in upper right corner of New Project dialog.  To make it AJAX enabled, just put ScriptManager in your page.

I don't have Web application with ASP.NET 2.0 Ajax Extensions 1.0 template in my VS 2008.

Comment: that's what I did and then I could not add the Ajax Control Toolkit in my ToolBox

Answer (score 0):

You need to create ASP.NET Web Application. Select .NET Framework 3.5 in upper right corner of New Project dialog and select target framework which you want.

[www.interviewsworld.com](http://www.interviewsworld.com)